# Should me make the tag 'agility' a synonym of 'dog-agility'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There are presently only two questions tagged `agility and five tagged`dog-agility'. Should we make `dog-agility` the master and `agility` a synonym?

Comment: Other way around I would think...

Comment: Merged into agility as a more generalized term.

Answer (score 4):

Agility should not go to Dog Agility, as other animals can be agile as well.

As John says in his comments making Dog Agility a synonym Agility would be a better choice.

Comment: OK, I agree, this makes sense.